# Creating a Powershell script to open as Administrator and run command

Tags: powershell

I'm new to Powershell scripting but have a need to create a script to run on everyone's computer in my office.  The script I need to run requires Powershell to run as Administrator.  When I use the "runas" command, another Powershell window opens but my commands run in the original Powershell window, which doesn't have sufficient privileges.  The commands I need to run in the Administrator window (privileges) are:

```
Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers -Name Microsoft.3DBuilder | Remove-AppxPackage
Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers -Name Microsoft.GetStarted | Remove-AppxPackage
Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers -Name Microsoft.Skypass | Remove-AppxPackage 
Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers -Name Microsoft.MicrosoftSolitaireCollection | Remove-AppxPackage
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [run powershell script as local admin](http://superuser.com/questions/1029464/run-powershell-script-as-local-admin)

Comment: Proper research is required before submitting questions here at Superuser.

Comment: I don't see this as a dupe of http://superuser.com/questions/1029464/run-powershell-script-as-local-admin. The proposed dupe has as an answer: Create a scheduled task, and encode the Credentials into the task, and launch that. **This** question is (IMO) about ps-remoting to "\\\ALLDOMAINPCs" in a script, and launching an ad-hoc series of commands. That may have other duplicates though.

Comment: You made no mention of running this on a PC connected to a active domain.  I still believe that creating a task, that runs a script with the permissions save of another user, is the way you will solve your problem.  Have you tried that?  How are you using `runas` exactly, you should be calling and elevating the permissions of Powershell.exe using the runas command.

Answer (score 3):

What version of powershell are you running?

If you are using 4.0 or above you can use the #Requires statement

In your case:

```
#Requires -RunAsAdministrator
```

When the script runs on the local machine it will ensure that the script is in elevated administrator mode.

Comment: "ensure that the script is in elevated administrator mode" should be "ensure that the script will only run in elevated administrator mode".